# Removing Left Recursions from the Production With Non-Terminals

Tags: context-free-grammar

HI,

I have a Production of the following form :

```
Expr ---> Primary | UnaryOp Expr | Expr BinOp Expr | id=Expr | id[Expr]=Expr.
```

Can anyone help me convert this into LL(1) form by removing the Left Recursions ??. I've banged my haad against this but I still can't get it :(. Following is my attempt.

---

```
Expr ---> Primary Expr' | UnaryOp Expr Expr' | id=Expr Expr' | id[Expr]=Expr Expr'

Expr' ---> BinOp Expr Expr' | epsilon
```

Is the above conversion correct ??. What am I doing from here ?.

I used the following general rule I found in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion#Removing_immediate_left_recursion).

---

```
A --->  Ab | B
```

when converted :

```
A' --->  aA'
A  --->  BA'
```

Answer (score 0):

The DragonBook explains really well how to convert from LR(0) to LL(1), and which grammars aren't LL(1), etc. If you're keen on learning this, you should take a look at the book's explanation.

Comment: Why do you think writing a parser is homework? I have written plenty for myself and open source projects of mine. Edit: I removed it from you answer. Feel free to revert if you insist :)

Comment: I feel converting an LR(0) grammar for Expressions to an LL(1) grammar is homework. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Expr ---> Primary Expr' | UnaryOp Expr | id=Expr | id[Expr]=Expr
Expr' ---> BinOp Expr | epsilon
```

the grammar containing left recursiveness is  `Expr ---> Expr BinOp Expr` 
what have been done is, remove left recursion from that

check whether is this correct by comparing with the article

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion

Answer (score 0):

```
Expr ---> Primary | UnaryOp Expr | Expr BinOp Expr | id=Expr | id[Expr]=Expr
```

it is easy to think of left recursion removal this way. 
you have a left recurs in  third expression 'Expr BinOp Expr'. You know that left 'Expr' term will get replaced by other terminals and expressions at some point of time (that is how we avoid left recursion). so lets do that --> replace problematic term with other expressions,

```
Expr ---> Primary BinOp Expr | UnaryOp Expr BinOp Expr | id=Expr  BinOp Expr | id[Expr]=Expr BinOp Expr | ( Primary | UnaryOp Expr | id=Expr | id[Expr]=Expr )
```

we see 'BinOp Expr' getting repeated. extract it out to another grammer , here's the final outcome

```
Expr' --> e | BinOp Expr

Expr -- > Primary Expr' | UnaryOp Expr Expr' | id=Expr Expr' | Primary Expr' | id[Expr]=ExprExpr'
```

Note e : which says expression can also be any of Primary , UnaryOp Expr ,etc